# How to run a local app on sauce labs?

Tags: protractor, saucelabs

I'm trying to get my tests running on saucelabs.

The app I'm testing is not publicly available since i want to test my app in my dev environment.

So i'm trying to use sauce connect.
I managed to create a tunnel but when I try to run tests on a vm using sauce connect i get a Bad gateway error.

For some reasons, my local app doesn't run on localhost but on test.example.com:3000

In dev, i use dnsmasq to reroute *.example.com through localhost.

I can't manage to do the same thing using sauce connect. I'll explain.

I've tried to just let dnsmasq do the work but it failed.

So i added the line :

```
test.example.com  localhost
```

to my `/etc/hosts` file
but it failed too.

Finally i tried to create a file name `/tmp/HOSTALIASES` with the same line in it then `export HOSTALIASES=/tmp/HOSTALIASES`

but it failed too.
I'm out of idea.

UPDATE

---

If i hit localhost:3000 , it does hit my local rails server but not for test.example.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So actually you need saucelab running as usual>

You can let dnsmasq running, i suspect it is not even aware of sauce connect running.

You need to add the line :

127.0.0.1     yourdomain.sub.com

you can't have localhost.